# Android sound only plays once

Tags: java, android, audio

I was making an app in java for android, and whenever a button is clicked, a sound plays. It works fine but pressing the button once makes it play, and then pressing that button or any other button doesn't do anything.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button s1, s2, s3, s4;
MediaPlayer ss1, ss2, ss3, ss4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linear);    

    s1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    s2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s2);
    s3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s3);
    s4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s4);

    s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            ss1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound1);
            ss1.start();
        }
    });

    s2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            ss2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound2);
            ss2.start();
        }
    });

    s3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            ss3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound3);
            ss3.start();
        }
    });

    s4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            ss4 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound4);
            ss4.start();
        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this way
Only use one `MediaPlayer`  and reuse it. Something like this

```
    MediaPlayer ss1;
    s1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    s2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s2);
    s3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s3);
    s4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s4);


    s1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){       
           public void onClick(View v){
                ss1= new MediaPlayer();
                ss1= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
                ss1.prepare();
                ss1.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll try this out in a bit and tell you if it works

Comment: I have a problem. ss1.setDataSource(R.raw.sound1); gives an error that The method setDataSource(String) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (int) and the solution is to change the type of sound1 to string, which I do, but that gives an error in R.java that it cannot convert from string to int, and changing that to int comes back to the same error.

Comment: context.getAssets() gives an error that context cannot be resolved. I tried changing it to MainActivity but it can't make a static reference, and "this" doesn't work either. Also, I'm assuming the filename in openFd goes between quotation marks?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but again it does not work. The error is at MediaPlayer.create that The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)

Comment: Make it MainActivity.this (this inside of the onclick is refering to the OnClickListener Class)

Comment: FYI, do not call prepare after MediaPlayer.create(...). This is specifically mentioned on the Android APIs.